# Как заставить ubuntu 18-04 увидеть принтер?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, virtualbox

Ubuntu 18-04 установлена на VirtualBox 6.0.4 с плагином Extension Pack. Принтер подключил через вкладку `Устройства -> USB` От основной системы он отключился с характерным звуком, но ubuntu упорно не хочет его видеть и пишет

> Sorry! The system printing service dosn`t seem to be available

Я уже провел sudo `apt-get update` и `sudo apt get upgrade` это не помогло. Как можно еще попробовать установить драйвер и заставить гостевую ОС видеть принтер?

Посмотрел через команду dmesg
Вот все что пишет касательно usb 1-2

```
usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
[ 3134.936750] usblp0: removed
[ 3152.692267] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ohci-pci
[ 3153.188398] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x1 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64    
[ 3153.188402] usb 1-2: config 1 interface 0 altsetting 0 endpoint 0x82 has invalid maxpacket 512, setting to 64
[ 3153.211980] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=132b, idProduct=2030
[ 3153.211986] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 3153.211990] usb 1-2: Product: PagePro 1350E
[ 3153.211993] usb 1-2: Manufacturer: KONICA MINOLTA
```

Помогите расшифровать

Хмм... Быстренько установил утилиту `hardinfo`. Во вкладке `USB-устройства` мой принтер есть, а во вкладке `Принтеры` нет... ничего не понимаю

Comment: для начала посмотрите в вывод dmesg, там часто бывают интересные вещи

Comment: @KoVadim Посмотрел последней строкой пишет, что к usb1-2 подключен мой принтер я так понял

Comment: @KoVadim Добавил, что пишет dmasg, принтер вроде определился

Comment: видимо теперь нужно настроить cups.

Comment: @Konstantin_SH Зря свой последний вопрос удалили, я уже ответ начал писать...

Comment: Что за принтер то?)

Comment: Дрова на купс ставьте и пойдет печатать. Тут через либусб похоже

Comment: Попробуйте использовать драйвера с https://www.openprinting.org/printer/Minolta/Minolta-PagePro_1350W